# MS SQL server 2005 - Error while querying with a column name as key

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a column name as "key". I am unable to filter based on that column

```
select * from myTable where key='someVal'
```

I get the following error

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'key'.
```

I cannot change the column name. How I can circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `key` is a keyword. If you have keywords as object names, you need to put them in brackets:

```
select * from myTable where [key]='someVal'
```